# I am getting error while using MAP in racket

Tags: dictionary, racket, pdp

I am very new to racket and started using lists examples recently, but when i run following map example:

```
(map sqrt (list 1 2 3 4))
```

I get this error: `map: this function is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

Racket has many languages. Which language are you using? If you're using, say, Beginning Student, it does not have any support for any higher-order functions, since beginners are not expected to know about those yet.

The standard Racket language (`#lang racket`) does have `map` built-in, of course. In fact, Intermediate Student and Advanced Student do, too.